# Allocation of object manager? for MMORPG

Tags: c#, oop, object

Can anyone suggest a clean way to do this.  I want a World with a dict of all instantiated objects in the game.  But I am not sure how to cast it right.

The objects should all be under 1 umbrella object and in 1 dict for easy saving / searching.

```
//all connected players
private Dictionary<IOClient, string> IOClients = new Dictionary<IOClient, string>();

player = new MObject(new object[]{result.Remove(0,1)}, 1);



public class MObject
{
    private Serial m_Serial;
    public Serial Serial { get { return m_Serial; } }

    public Player player = null;
    public Item item = null;

    public MObject(object[] obj, int type)
    {
      //  m_Serial = Serial.NewMobile;
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Player) || type == 1)
        {
            player = new Player((string)obj[0]);
        }
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Item) || type == 2)
        {
         //   item = new Item();
        }
    }
}


//Also a World
public static class World
{
    private static bool m_Loading;
    private static bool m_Loaded;

    private static Dictionary<Serial, MObject> m_MObjects;

    public static Dictionary<Serial, MObject> MObjects
    { get { return m_MObjects; } }
}
```

Comment: Please inline code into the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Added for OP :)

Comment: updated. SHould be good.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually explain your problem?

Comment: I don't feel right using obj[] and constantly casting things.  There should be a better way to do this no?

Comment: how about a dictionary of typed dictionaries (each typed dictionary containing only objects of a particular (base) type)?

Comment: It also depends on how you intent to look objects up.  Are there different types of look-ups to find objects?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the core issue here is one of weak verses strong typing.

One possible solution is to introduce interfaces to your objects and have one or more dictionaries specific to each interface.

e.g

You have dictionary for all IDrawable objects, another for all ICanShoot objects, another for all ICanBeShot objects and so on.

That way, each time you use one of the dictionaries, you shouldn't need to cast... and you the get added bonus of loose coupling etc.

If you want to extend this idea one step further, it might be possible to wrap the dictionaries into an IOC container.... but that's a whole topic unto itself.